# Spring Jpa @Procedure not working correctly

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Trying to call my stored proc...

Repo looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {
    @Procedure(name="getTopItems")
    public List<Item> getTopItems(int top);
}
```

Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Items")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="getTopItems", procedureName="pr_getTopItems", resultClasses={ Item.class },
                           parameters={ @StoredProcedureParameter(name="top", type=Integer.class, mode=ParameterMode.IN) })
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "itemId", "description" })
public class Item {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes="Id of the item.", required=true, value="100000")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty(access=Access.READ_ONLY)
    private int itemId = 0;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes="Item description.", required=true, value="Item1")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=256)
    private String description;
    private int viewed;

    public int getItemId() {
        return this.itemId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getViewed() {
        return this.viewed;
    }
}
```

When I try to run, I get an exception:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.HashMap] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure
>   org.xxx.yyy.items.models.Item]

The SP returns columns named `ItemId`, `Description`, `Viewed`.

Isn't the mapping supposed to be auto-magical? This is new code, so I'm looking for the latest & greatest Nov 2019 way of doing it :).

I'm using the standard `findAll()` as well and it maps correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already face this issue a few months ago. Try with the annotation `@Query` in your repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="call your_procedure(:your_parameter)")
    public List<Item> getTopItems(int top);
}
```

I hope this should work.

Comment: hmm... it does work... is this the right way to do it? All the examples show @Parameter?

Comment: @SledgeHammer it should work with those annotations, but for a reason I don't really know why. The `@Query` allows you to do a native procedure call. It works for me. Also delete the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation as you define the `@Query` annotation in the repository.

Comment: I get ```No property <name-of-procedure-goes-here> found for type <name-of-entity>!```. This is when I use ```@Query(nativeQuery=true...)```. When I use ```@Procedure```, the console shows that it creates the query ```{CALL <procedure-name>(?)}``` but it tells me that I need to use the native query annotation. WTF